# Подсчёт спарсеных данных

Tags: c#

Парсю вот так ID

```
var match = Regex.Match(text_get, @"<id>(.*?)</id>");
```

Как узнать. Какое кол-во id я получил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном примере вы всегда получите одно `id` (первое), независимо от того, сколько их было в исходной строке.

Чтобы получить все вхождения регулярного выражения в заданную строку, используйте метод [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx). Он возвращает коллекцию совпадений. Вот небольшой пример:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text_get, @"<id>(.*?)</id>");
int count = matches.Count;
```

Comment: `     string pattern = @"<id>(.*?)</id>";
               foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text_get, pattern))
               {

               }` 


Пишет ошибку Неявное преобразование типа "int" в "string"

Comment: Не вижу ошибки в приведенном фрагменте. Внимательно просмотрите свой код.

Comment: Ошибку указывает тут  Regex.Matches(text_get, pattern)
А есть какие нибудь другие примеры парсинга?

Comment: Вот все возможные вызовы этого метода: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(v=vs.110).aspx . Там же есть и рабочий пример.